# C++ Builder - Fatal error: Parameter "write" cannot be null

Tags: c++builder

Установил **Embarcadero Rad Studio C++ Builder 2010**. При компиляции любого проекта выдает ошибку:

> [Fatal error] Parameter "write" cannot be null`

Даже, если только создать новый проект.

Как исправить? Весь интернет перелопатил, похожей ошибки нигде не видел.

Comment: на какую то строку кода ругается или как целиком все выглядит?

Comment: [тут](http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=295352&st=0) нечто подобное было, возможно. решили переустановкой net framework 1.1. вы стэк трейс посмотрите там, если вдруг у вас тоже заканчивается на каком нить `dotnetcoreide120.bpl` то копайте в сторону `.net`

Answer (score 0):

Была та же проблема сразу после установки Embarcadero Rad Studio Delphi 2010 на чистую Windows 10 1703, после апдейта до 1709 пропала сама собой.